# How to correctly scale and position a view

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, scale

I have a UIView that originally is the size of 320x90

now I want to scale it, so I wrote

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9,0.8);
```

the problem is that now my view doesn't sit where I want it to sit, x,y wise

and any changes to its frame's origin does not change its location on the screen

how to put location on the screen after scaling ?

Comment: Try settings the view's `center` property. That's best when using transforms.

Comment: unfortunately with myView.center = CGPointMake(something, something) view still doesnt budge

Comment: Are you using auto layout or constraints that might keep the view from moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing another transform for your offset by using [CGAffineTransformTranslate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformTranslate)?:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(myView.transform, x, y);
```

Comment: thank you, i didnt know you could transform a transform, but then my linear algebra didnt suffer for that ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, in fact, you can apply your scaling to the view's existing transform too. That might avoid the need to do the subsequent translation altogether: